# Parallel Browser Execution Possible in Cucumber (Java / Maven)?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, cucumber, testng

Parallel Browser Execution Possible in Cucumber (Java / Maven)?

For example I know its definately possible using TestNG when Cucumber is not involved, but is it even possible embedding Java, Cucumber, jUnit and TestNG together?

I have tried the following TestNG.xml file which points a runner class which then point to multiple feature files but have had no success :/

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Automation_Scripts" verbose="2"  parallel="classes" thread-count="2">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="Framework.utilities.RetryListner"></listener>
    </listeners>

    <test name="Automation Tests">
        <packages>
            <package name="TestFramework.ncc.*"></package>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: It is supposed to work. You should describe more your problem and share more thing in order to have a more global view.

Answer (score 1):

There are no built in capabilities in cucumber for this as far as I know, but I have seen an approach where different sets of Cucumber scenarios are run by different junit classes which are then run in parallel.

Defining which scenarios are run by which class can be achieved by using either tags or defining different features for he different runner classes.

There is a maven plugin that seems to automate that approach: https://github.com/temyers/cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using TestNG using cucumber.

For achieving this, you have to have independent test runners for each feature file.

eg:

TestRunnerA points to feature A in some folder

TestRunnerB points to feature B in some folder or the same

Specify the exact file in features (in cucumber options) if all features are in same folder.

And then you can specify them as separate testsin testNG xml and they will run parallely.

A sample of it can be seen here
[Link](http://www.sahajamit.com/post/cucumber-jvm-with-testng/)

Answer (score 0):

Jithu Paul answer is how this is typically approached, and this is mainly because each runner class needs to have slightly unique cucumber options for outputting test results (i.e. unique JSON file names). This roundabout way is due to not being able to parameterise Java annotations. However you can rename cucumber options dynamically using java reflection.
This project has a good example: 
https://github.com/workpeter/ARGOS

In particular the runner class. As of today its located here:
https://github.com/workpeter/ARGOS/blob/master/src/test/java/integrationTests/cucumber/Runner.java